# First discovery of long-term depression?

Tags: neuroscience, history

LTP was first described by Tim Bliss and Terje Lømo in their paper [Long-lasting potentiation of synaptic transmission in the dentate area of the anaesthetized rabbit following stimulation of the perforant path.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/4727084)

When was LTD first described? By whom?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The process of long-term depression (LTD) was first discovered in the cerebellum by Ito *et al.* in 1982:

Ito M, Kano M. [Long-lasting depression of parallel fiber-Purkinje cell transmission induced by conjunctive stimulation of parallel fibers and climbing fibers in the cerebellar cortex.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/6298664) Neurosci Lett. 1982;33(3):253-8

Ito M, Sakurai M and Tongroach P. [Climbing fibre induced depression of both mossy fibre responsiveness and glutamate sensitivity of cerebellar Purkinje cells](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1250696/). Journal of Physiology 1982; 324: 113–134.

Check this [source](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1038/npg.els.0000033/full).